# Expanding macro for sorting and copy/pasting data to other worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I export a schedule from MS Teams to Excel for data manipulation.

I made a macro that changes the dates field to a date format for the EU and sorts by it by date.
Then it goes to the next worksheet and checks the names of employees and creates a worksheet for each of the names.
Then it jumps back to the first worksheet, sorts by "name" criteria and copies the data for every single one to its own respective worksheet.

This is what I got so far that is OK:

```vb
Sub Temp1()

'Convert Cell Format from Text to Date and change MDY to DMY Format
    Sheets("Shifts").Select
    Range("D2:D1000").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
      FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("F2:F1000").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
      FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True  
        
'Add the Sheets for each member of the "Members" Sheet
    Sheets("Members").Select
    Dim xRg As Excel.Range
    Dim wSh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wBk As Excel.Workbook
    Set wSh = ActiveSheet
    Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xRg In wSh.Range("A2:A22")
        With wBk
            .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Evidencija radnog vremena"
            Selection.Font.Size = 20
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Godina i mjesec"
            Selection.Font.Size = 14
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Radnik"
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select     
                               
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xRg.Value
            Range("B2").Value = ActiveSheet.Name
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                Debug.Print xRg.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
'Sort by Date
    Sheets("Shifts").Select
    Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

After this I need some kind of loop or switch case or Foreach - i don't know what exactly.
I have it hardcoded for now, but it will become bulky, slow and problematic to maintain.

What I need to do:
Go through the list of employees, find for the employee all data and copy it to his respective worksheet - which has already been created.

Here is the hardcoded version of the code:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$276").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
  "Employee name"
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Employee name").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
Columns("A:L").AutoFit
For Each r In Range("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    r.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    If r.Value Like "*Home Office*" Then r.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r.Value Like "*Neradni dan*" Then r.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r.Value Like "*Bolovanje*" Then r.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    If r.Value Like "*Godišnji odmor*" Then r.Interior.ColorIndex = 29
Next

Columns("L").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("J").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("H").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("B").EntireColumn.Delete
Columns("G").EntireColumn.Delete
```

I copied the whole code below.

A clarification of what it needs to do:

1. sort the data in the first worksheet - already handled
2. create the worksheets by the names in the 3rd worksheet - working
3. On the first sheet, that is already "sorted" - I need to go through all the names, copy the the data that is relevant to the sheet - i.e the sheets are named by names that are found in row a. so i need it to go through the first worksheet, need all the data that has the same name in the row a and copy it to the respective sheet. - PLEASE HELP :)

```vb
Sub TEMPExcelObradiTablicuZaObracunPlaca()

'Convert Cell Format from Text to Date and change MDY to DMY Format
    Sheets("Shifts").Select
    Range("D2:D1000").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
      FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("F2:F1000").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
      FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
                   
'Ovdje dodajem potrebne Sheetove iz Members Sheeta
    Sheets("Members").Select
    Dim xRg As Excel.Range
    Dim wSh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wBk As Excel.Workbook
    Set wSh = ActiveSheet
    Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xRg In wSh.Range("A2:A22")
        With wBk
            .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Evidencija radnog vremena"
            Selection.Font.Size = 20
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Radnik"
            Selection.Font.Size = 14
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Godina i mjesec"
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
            'Range("B2).Value = DateAdd(mmmm, yyyy) -> OVDJE SAM ZAPEO TU NASTAVITI!!! - dodavanje datuma u b2 celiju!
                               
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xRg.Value
            Range("B2").Value = ActiveSheet.Name
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                Debug.Print xRg.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
'Sort by Date
    Sheets("Shifts").Select
    Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Define LASTROW to find the last row and column in Members Sheetu!

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Range("A1").Resize(LastRow, LastColumn).Select

'Proba ForEach petlje
' Creating a range of sheet names from the data on Members
    Dim SheetNamesRange As Range
    Set SheetNamesRange = Sheets("Members").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

' Iterate through all sheets in the range and write the word "Updated" in cell B2
    Dim SheetName As Variant, SheetNameString As String
    For Each SheetName In SheetNamesRange
    
        ' OVDJE SAM ISKOMENTIRAO OVA 2 REDA
        'SheetNameString = CStr(SheetName)
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNameString).Range("Q2") = "Updated"
        
        Sheets("Shifts").Range("$A$1:$L$276").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SheetNameString"
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        'SheetNameString = CStr(SheetName)
        Sheets.CStr(SheetNameString).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
        Columns("A:L").AutoFit
        For Each r In Range("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            If r.Value Like "*Home Office*" Then r.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            If r.Value Like "*Neradni dan*" Then r.Interior.Color = vbRed
            If r.Value Like "*Bolovanje*" Then r.Interior.Color = vbBlue
            If r.Value Like "*Godišnji odmor*" Then r.Interior.ColorIndex = 29
        Next
        Columns("L").EntireColumn.Delete
        Columns("J").EntireColumn.Delete
        Columns("H").EntireColumn.Delete
        Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete
        Columns("B").EntireColumn.Delete
        Columns("G").EntireColumn.Delete
    Next SheetName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, a `For Each` loop can be used here.  Here is some code that outlines the basic principle:

```
Private Sub Shone()

    ' Creating a range of sheet names from the data on Sheet1
    Dim SheetNamesRange As Range
    Set SheetNamesRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3")

    ' Iterate through all sheets in the range and write the word "Updated" in cell B2
    Dim SheetName As Variant, SheetNameString As String
    For Each SheetName In SheetNamesRange
    
        SheetNameString = CStr(SheetName)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNameString).Range("B2") = "Updated"
        
    Next SheetName

End Sub
```

In this example, I want to grab the names of sheets written on Sheet1, and write the word "Updated" in cell B2 on each of those sheets.

The cells A1, A2, and A3 on the sheet Sheet1 contain the following text, respectively, "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3".  First, I create a `Range` of data.  That data is just the sheet names in cells A1:A3.  It goes without saying that your `Range` will contain different data, but I believe that you have already taken care of that part.

Next, I iterate through that `Range` of data.  A `For Each` loop requires the iterator (in this case, the variable `SheetName`) to be a `Variant` datatype. As I iterate through all of the sheets, I finally get to what I want to do: write the word "Updated" in cell B2.  Finally, we reach the `Next` statement which tells us that the next step of the `For Each` loop will start, if there are any more members in the `SheetNamesRange` to iterate through.

Comment: thanks for the help so far, can u please look at the edit. thnks in advance!

Comment: @Shone You're welcome..  It's not a good idea to edit your existing question to ask a new question, though.  I suggest this: ask a new question but only include the relevant code and problem.  No need to tell us about the code that is working.  Just ask about the copying data part, because that is your problem.  The shorter and clearer your question is, the more likely people will want to help.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will post a new question soon, I have had some ideas i would like to try first! Thanks again for your help!